# Combining LaTeX3 conditionals

Tags: latex3

Let's say that I want to iterate on the lines of a file and try to do a regex replace on each line, and do something with the outcome if there is a match, but there are in fact two regexes and I want to act (the same way) if either matches, avoiding code duplication. My current code looks like this:

```latex
\cs_new:Nn \vb_or:nnTF { #1 { #3 } { #2 { #3 } { #4 } } }

\ior_str_map_variable:NNn \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str 
    { \vb_or:nnTF 
        { \regex_replace_once:NnNTF \c_first_regex { foo } \l_tmpa_str }
        { \regex_replace_once:NnNTF \c_second_regex { bar } \l_tmpa_str }
        { \typeout{\l_tmpa_str} } 
        {}
    }
```

The utility function `\vb_or:nnTF` feels like it exists somewhere already, but on the other hand it is very brittle with respect to `T`, `F`, `TF` variants and I fear that it might rely on implementation details to work. OTOH setting booleans and so on is much more verbose. What would be the proper way?

Comment: normally you should have also a predicate version, and then you can do `\bool_if:n {\vb_foo_p:n{whatever} || \vb_bar_p:n{something} }`

Comment: Agreed if I am providing the macro. In my use case I actually use `\regex_replace_once:NnNTF` and `\regex_replace_once:NnNp` is not available

Comment: well improve your question. Obviously you forgot to mention quite some important details.

Comment: Since you're using unexpandable tests, is your question about a more robust version of `\vb_or:nnTF`? The restriction that it works only with `TF` variants seems fine to me (it looks like something you want to use as an internal anyway).

Comment: Edited to be closer to my actual use case. I'm fine with restricting to `TF` variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way would be to also provide a `_p` variant and combine them with the functions of the `l3bool` module, like so:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vb_foo:n #1 { p, TF, T, F }
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { foo } {#1}
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vb_bar:n #1 { p, TF, T, F }
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { bar } {#1}
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_lazy_or:nnTF
  { \vb_foo_p:n { bar } }
  { \vb_bar_p:n { bar } }
  { True }
  { False }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Note that this is only possible with fully expandable tests (if your test isn't expandable, you can't create a working `p` variant, or use it in a bool-expression).

If you can't create an expandable version, I'd probably really provide a wrapper similar to yours (though I'd define it with `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn`). So in that case I'd use something like the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \vb_protected_or:nn #1#2 { TF, T, F }
  {
    #1
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { #2 \prg_return_true: \prg_return_false: }
  }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vb_foo:n #1 { p, TF, T, F }
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { foo } {#1}
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vb_bar:n #1 { p, TF, T, F }
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { bar } {#1}
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_lazy_or:nnTF
  { \vb_foo_p:n { bar } }
  { \vb_bar_p:n { bar } }
  { True }
  { False }
\par
\vb_protected_or:nnTF
  { \vb_foo:nTF { bar } }
  { \vb_bar:nTF { bar } }
  { True }
  { False }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

or use temporary boolean variables I'd set dependent on the result of your tests.

Also, in your code the second regex replacement isn't applied if the first matched. If the second should also always be used, I'd probably use a temporary boolean variable:

```
\bool_new:N \l_vb_tmpa_bool
\ior_str_map_variable:NNn \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str 
    {
      \bool_set_false:N \l_vb_tmpa_bool
      \regex_replace_once:NnNT \c_vb_first_regex { foo } \l_tmpa_str
        { \bool_set_true:N \l_vb_tmpa_bool }
      \regex_replace_once:NnNT \c_vb_second_regex { bar } \l_tmpa_str
        { \bool_set_true:N \l_vb_tmpa_bool }
      \bool_if:NT \l_vb_tmpa_bool
        { \typeout { \l_tmpa_str } }
    }
```

Comment: So if my `\vb_foo:nTF` is actually a library function taking several arguments and not providing the `p` variant, your advice would be to wrap it into a new conditional of my own with the `p` variant? I like it

Comment: @VincentBeffara if the library function is fully expandable, yes, but chances are that it isn't if no `p` variant is provided. You can see whether the library function is expandable if it has a star next to it.

Comment: Ah, I am beginning to understand. Question updated to more closely match my setup...

Comment: @Vincent modification of variables can _never_ be expandable.